# How to fetch data from Zoho Books to Zoho Creator? 200+ records

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

I need to fetch Data from Zoho Books to Zoho Creator.
How to get Invoice, Estimate, Customer data?

How to fetch 200+ records?

Through single API call we will get only 200 records.

Answer (score 1):

1. First we have to make a connection from **Zoho Creator to Zoho Books** ,
   For that Go to Zoho Creator/ Setup/ Connection and **Make a connection** (Select Zoho books module only).
   Now you have to go to Zoho Books and in settings you will find **User and Roles**, Assign user to that email in which you want to fetch the data. Make that email Role as Admin.
   you need to accept the invitation from Zoho books.

For example here I am fetching Invoice module from Zoho Books to Zoho Creator.

```html
void invoice()
{
    organizationID =  input org_id number;
    invlist = List();
    pageList = {1,2,3};
    itemList = List();
    customerList = List();
    i = 0;
    for each  page in pageList
    {
        i = i + 1;
        invoices = invokeurl
[
    url :"https://books.zoho.in/api/v3/invoices?page=" + page + "&per_page=200&organization_id=" + organizationID
    type :GET
    connection:"zohobooks"
];
        invoices = invoices.get("invoices");
        info "invoices" + invoices;
        for each  findItems in invoices
        {
            info "findItems" + findItems;
            invoiceID = findItems.get("invoice_number");
            customerID = findItems.get("customer_name");
            balanceID = findItems.get("balance");
            dateID = findItems.get("date");
            amountID = findItems.get("total");
            itemID = findItems.get("line_items");
            statusID = findItems.get("status");

          // Invoice is form name, We are inserting data in that form

                insert into Invoice
                [
                    Added_User=zoho.loginuser
                    Invoice_Number=invoiceID
                    Customer_Name=customerID
                    Balance=balanceID
                    Date_field=dateID
                    Amount=amountID
                    Status=statusID
                ]
            }
    }
    info invlist;
}
```